# transpose same single column range from multiple worksheets onto single worksheet

Tags: transpose

I have an indefinite number of multiple worksheets from which I am trying to transpose a single column range (i.e., "C4" on down) from each onto a single summary worksheet.  The column range is the same for all worksheets.  The code I've adapted from other posts have gotten me close but when I transpose the column from each worksheet it seems it only transposes them onto one row ("F4").  Could someone please try and see what I'm missing?  Greatly appreciated!!  This is the code I've been working with:

```
    Sub UpdateSummary()

    Dim rng3 As Range, sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long

    'the "sample" work sheet has the total # of rows; used to count # rows
    'which will be needed from each of the other worksheets

    lastRow = Worksheet("sample").Range("J3").End(xlDown).Row

    'the workbook has multiple worksheets numbered from 1 to n

    Sheets("summary").Activate
    For Each sh In Worksheets
         If sh.Name <> "summary" _
         And sh.Name <> "sample" Then

         'if i don't add the +1 it's short by 1
          Set rng3 = sh.Range("C4:C" & lastRow + 1)

           rng3.Copy

           'using Transpose so for each sh its range goes into the summary as 
           'rows (starts from F4 because the top 3 rows are headers)
           Worksheets("summary").Range("F4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
         End If
       Next sh
    End Sub
```

In thinking this through... I think part of what it needs is to count the number of worksheets from which ranges will be copied/transposed - and use that number of total worksheets as the number of rows on which the data will be transposed?

I got it... I needed to reset the target range by Offsetting it. This is the code that worked:

```
    Sub CalcSummary()
      'vba to calculate summary
      'for all worksheets except sample and summary
      'select range to copy values
      'transpose values onto summary sheet

      Dim rng3 As Range
      Dim sh As Worksheet
      Dim cases As Long
      Dim items As Long
      Dim trng As Range

      cases = Worksheets("sample").Range("A3").End(xlUp).Row
      items = Worksheets("sample").Range("J3").End(xlDown).Row
      Set trng = Worksheets("summary").Range("F4")

      Sheets("summary").Activate
      For Each sh In Worksheets

        If sh.Name <> "summary" _
        And sh.Name <> "sample" Then
          Set rng3 = sh.Range("C4:C" & items + 1)
          rng3.Copy

            With trng
              .PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            End With
          Set trng = trng.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
      Next sh
      MsgBox "Summary sheet updated successfully."

    End Sub
```

Hope this helps for anyone else who needs to do something similar ;) And thanks for all those who maybe were trying to rewrite the code for me.